# Install windows service using command promt

Tags: .net, windows-services

I am installing a windows service using visual studio command prompt using the following command

> ```
> installutil D:\Folder1\Projectname\bin\Debug\Service1.exe
> ```

But I get the following exception

> Exception occurred while initializing the
>   installation:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or
>   assembly 'file:///D:\Folder1\WIN' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified..

Is the command wrong or Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Installutil is the correct app. Did you surround the file path with quotes? If not, the first whitespace will cause a problem.

Comment: no, I have not used quotes. I have given one space after installutil command. Is that the problem?

Comment: I posted an answer illustrating the point.

Comment: Got it, space and quotes were the problem...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

File paths with spaces in them must be quoted.

**Good**

```
installutil "c:\my directory\service1.exe"
```

**Bad**

```
installutil c:\my directory\service1.exe
```

*The OS stops reading the path at the first space, causing it to look for a file named"c:\my", which does not exist.*

Answer (score 6):

i have the same problem,
in this case Service.exe was blocked.

Solution :
right-click on the file and open Properties. You may see a message – This file came from another computer and might be blocked to help protect this computer. Click on the Unblock button and then on Apply/OK

Answer (score 1):

Missing quotes was the problem.
Installutil "path of exe/d"

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these kind of errors follow these step:

1. Run command prompt with "As Administrator"
2. Change command prompt directory to your service exe file.

After this execute

```
command> installutil service1.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Run Developer command prompt as administrator mode.
2) and make below changes

```
installutil -i "D:\Folder1\Projectname\bin\Debug\Service1.exe"
```